# How to convert or save image in bytes to send them through SMS?

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-api

*** Current situation:**

I have an app that will take a picture, this picture becomes base64 string. So I have a something like this:

> ```
>  data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAzwAAAO9CAYAAABHGmKTAAAACXBIWXMAAA9hAA
> ```

I Have the following code, that actually works with the link of an image.

```
var picture = 'http://tonsofcats.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/d6040e929550e65fcf1aacbbf0f58e5f-550x411.jpg';

client.messages.create({ 
    to: "+6548554654645", 
    from: "+14654561878", 
    body: "Testing - Testing - Testing - Testing", 
    mediaUrl: picture 
}, function(err, message) { 
    console.log(message.sid);  
});
```

All of this code, works perfectly. But now I need to send an image that is a base64 string.

Is there a way I can send the image? Like decode it, or save it in cache to be able to send it?

When I try to send the encoded base64 string instead of the URL, I get this error.

[image]

Decided to change up a bit the code to see what error I am getting: Found the following:

[image]

So, I see that it's a JSON problem, when is trying to send a huge string encoded image

**UPDATE**

When I console.log(message). This is the message that I get:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert image into base64 string using javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript)

Comment: If the rendered page is just doing something like `<img src="{{message.mediaUrl}}" />` It will still work fine. You can use the base64 string as an img src.

Comment: You should be able to just provide the base64 string in place of the URL.

Comment: @TheJim01 I keep getting and error when I send the string as it is.

Comment: @Monica What error are you receiving?

Comment: Maybe I am mistaken, but... an SMS is limited to 140 characters, isn't it?

Comment: @Psi 160. Twitter introduced the 140 limit because it reserved 20 characters for its use.

Comment: Right, thanks, but anyway hard to believe that a data url will fit into this little space (unless using multi-sms which is likely not to be applicable here)

Comment: @TheJim01 The error seems to be coming from Twilio. But anyway. I just want to send the data URL.

Comment: @Monica Twilio evangelist here.  What is the error being returned by Twilio?  As long as the URL you are providing as the value of MediaUrl is publicly accessible, what you have looks correct.

Comment: @Monica I re-read your question, and I'm not sure exactly what you already tried. For all intents and purposes, a dataURL _is_ a URL (and in this case a URL to an image). So if you put your dataURL in place of the image URL in your example (`var picture = 'data:image/png;base64,iVB...';`), it should "just work."

Comment: @TheJim01 Yeah I already tried that, but gives me an error. I guess the encoded string is too big to send it by sms. I have to figure out something else. But right now I suspect this is the problem

Comment: @Monica As Devin mentioned, can you please post the error you're receiving? That will help us pin it down.

Comment: @DevinRader I updated the question with the error that I am getting. Is not very useful I think.

Comment: @TheJim01  I updated the question with the error that I am getting. Is not very useful I think.

Comment: @Monica Your error is telling you where the problem lies. Look in `send-sms.js`, line 85. It's trying to access property "`sid`" of an object which is `undefined`. Figuring out why that object is undefined will get you to the next step of solving this problem.

Comment: @TheJim01 I tried debugging this, but at the end I just decided to print the  error instead of the message and I got a different error. I think the problem is JSON or how I am sending the encoded string

Comment: @Monica Is that second screenshot the result of `console.log(err)`?  Can you also log out the `message` parameter?

Comment: @DevinRader. Yes that is the error from console.log(err). And the first one is from trying to console.log "message.sid"

Comment: @Monica can you `console.log(message)`

Comment: @DevinRader It displays undefined. Are you sure I can send the entire encoded base64 string? When I send the http url with the image it works, but when I encode it, it just doesn't work. And Twilio has no more documentation on how to do this.

Comment: `mediaUrl` only accepts a publicly accessible URL as a value.  You can't send an encoded image in that parameter.  If you are setting `picture` to some value other than a URL (as you've shown in your post above) that won't work and is probably what Twilio is complaining about.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio doesn't have documentation on this. So the only thing you can do in this situation is decode the base64 String and save it or cache it so that you can have an actual URL to be able to send via SMS. mediaUrl only accepts http or https urls.